# ASP.net MVC eonasdan-datetimepicker Unable to change the datetime format

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, momentjs, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm trying to change the format of my DateTime value as "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm A", example: 18th June 2017, 11:30 AM should be displayed as 18-06-2017 11:30 AM in the textbox area.
I'm fetching the values of datetime field from database and I'm unable to change the value in the DateTime Picker in the required format.

I'm using Eonasdan Bootstrap DateTimePicker.
https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

**The only format that works is YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A.
The required format "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm A" produces datetime in some unreadable format like Di-06-yyyy 07:13 PM.**

Below is what I'm currently having:-

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: '@Model.StartTime',
    minDate: new Date(),
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A',
    showTodayButton: true,
    sideBySide : true,     
    showClose: true,
    showClear: true,
    toolbarPlacement: 'top'
});
```

With my `ASP.net MVC` code:-

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartTime)               
</td>
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Employee", new { startTime = item.StartTime}) 
</td>
```

And in my `C#` code,

```
[Display(Name = "Scheduled Time")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm}")]
public DateTime StartTime { get;set;}
```

I've attached the below link for screenshot of the Page:-

[DateTime Picker Format Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BYSO.png)

Is there any way I can change the date in the required format with this Eonasdan DateTimePicker?

Comment: Since the working format has different capitalization have you tried using that? DD-MM-YYYY etc?

Comment: Hi Sami. 
I tried the format "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm A" but the textbox appears blank upon loading. The editable date appear only after I click on the textbox. The date appears in the required format but the time is not picked correctly. Its picking the current time instead like -9:03 AM.
 How can I make it appear in the beginning itself, currently I'm using "defaultDate: '@Model.StartTime'" to pick the existing value.

Answer (score 0):

Casing of the format string is important. `DD` is used to display the day number with leading zero if necessary (e.g. "02"), `dd` displays the day of week abbreviation (e.g. "Di" for Tuesday in German locale).

Another point of confusion is that the datetimepicker uses moment.js format specifiers, not C# format specifiers.

So your format string in the JavaScript part should be `DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm A`.

Refer to the [moment.js documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for valid format strings.